# Apparently patent redundancy in a "because" construction

Tags: meaning, grammar, redundancy, equivalence

Sentences such as the following can be found ([language log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494)).

- The reason he left is because he was not respected. (1)

They can be transformed as follows.

- He left [for the reason that/because] he was not repected. ("for the reason that" *is equivalent to* "because") (2)

It follows that when using (1) the speaker is really saying (3) below.

- The reason he left is for the reason that he was not repected. (*substitution of equivalent phrase from (2)*) (3)

Should we recognize a redundancy in this formulation (I think we should), or is there a way to resolve this apparent problem? Which is it?

Comment: Yes, I consider that there is a redundancy there; I would say "The reason is **that**..."

Comment: Apparent problem? I don't see any logic in your claim. The usual form in a relative construction is "The reason (why/that) he left is that he was not respected". The non-relative "He left because he was not respected" is also fine and common.

Comment: @BillJ It is very apparent to me, and frankly I can't see how (1) could be justified, unless the equivalence I perceive is an error, but I do not see that error if it is there.

Comment: I disagree that there is an equivalence between (1) and (3). On what grounds do you claim that there is?

Comment: @BillJ That seems evident; it's only needed to read "because=for the reason that"; that is in that point that could be hidden  some  error.

Comment: @BillJ This reasoning is strictly personal; I just verified now after your comment that as a conjunction "because" does mean "for the reason that" (SOED), as it seemed inescapable to me.

Comment: We don't say "The reason he left is because ... . Btw, in modern grammar "because" is a preposition, not a conjunction.

Comment: You can leave because of a *reason* which is generally a clear and conscious thought, or due to other vaguer circumstances that don't constitute a reason. Although I think *the reason is* is often used simply for emphasis. I don't entirely understand the nuances of the question though.

Comment: @StuartF What the OP is saying is that if "because" means "for the reason that", then semantically it duplicates the meaning of "reason" in "The **reason** he left is **because** he was not respected".

Comment: "apparently patent" → *apparently easily recognizable* or *apparently obvious* … I think you're in the same glass house.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs The way I see it is that the redundancy seems evident, so it is a patent redundancy, but on second thought what seems to be an evidence could be mere appearance, therefore the thing is presented as being apparently that.  However it seems that you are saying that this title itself contains a redundancy; I don't understand that. It seems also that you might be saying that "apparently" cannot modify "patent"; should it be "apparent patent redundancy" then (where "apparent" modifies "patent redundancy")? (apparent: seemingly true but maybe not so).

Answer (score 0):

You might find this article helpful https://www.merriam-webster.com/grammar/usage-of-reason-is-because-redundant

One of the points mentioned:

'Sentences of the form "If you're tired, it's because you stayed up all night playing video games again" are certainly recognizable as standard English. If because can refer to a pronoun like it or to the also common this or that ("this/that is because"), there is no logical reason it should not refer to a noun like reason. Thus, the grammatical objection to "the reason is because" doesn't hold up.'

Comment: It is therefore to be acknowledged as an accepted redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason he left is because he was not respected.

That's the kind of sentence a teacher of expository writing would flag as *verbose*  or *chatty/talky*, not as ungrammatical. A succinct version would be:

> He left because he was not respected.

A teacher of fiction writing might welcome the original version as being true to how many people speak.